# Sitefinity 8.2: Related Data for product variants

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-8

I've tried asking this on the main Sitefinity forums but had no luck as such.

I have a given scenario and I am wondering how this could be structured in the Sitefinity eCommerce module.

I essentially have two product types, a full product and spare part. As expected spare parts relate to full products and some spare parts can relate to different full products.

I have modeled this structure in Sitefinity fine using a Related Data property on the full product with the ability to select multiple spare parts per product.

My issue arises when I create variants of the full product and the main variant attribute is essentially the design print on the full product. I need to be able to associate a spare part to a specific variant, an example being a replacement cover that has the specific design print on so can only ever be associated with a variant of a full product. So in effect I just need a Related Data property against the variant rather than the product itself if that makes sense.

Is this possible out of the box in Sitefinity? If not, can I structure my product / spare parts in manner that I can query spare parts on a variant basis? Or do I need to model this outside of Sitefinity?

Thanks.

PS I am fairly new to Sitefinity development so if there is anything I could have missed please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried the approach detailed here http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-add-custom-fields-for-product-variations? Not sure if it could be adapted for a related data field thought.

Comment: @ArtofCode Thanks. So I'm assuming that I would just execute this code as a one off then that creates the relationship into the CMS database and amends the back end designers to expose the new property. The only reason I ask is that there isn't any real context to the example given.

Comment: Yes, the way I have added MetaFields before is in `Application_Start` in `Global.cs`. You should be able to update the product variation definition through the CMS as well as programmatically. Go to `Settings -> Advanced -> Catalog -> Controls -> ProductVariationBackendDefinition -> Views -> 
ProductVariationsBackendEdit -> Sections -> VariationPropertiesSection -> Fields`

Comment: I attempted to following the example but failed to understand what it was doing. Anyway I then attempted to build the relationship through the backend settings of which I was partially successful. I am now able to select 'Spare Part' product types as part of a RelatedData field on the product variation property view, but now I get some script error when I select spare parts. I have a feeling it's to do with a misconfigured 'RelatedDataProvider', but I'm not quite sure which type this is??